# Susbtract a character plus a possible "," after and before him in a string comma separated

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Those are the cases on table column `post_attending`, `post_attending` could be: `5` or `5,6,7` or `6,7,5` or `6,5,7` or `''` or longer string comma separated and 5 on this or not.
How should I do to delete "5" and "possible" `,` surrounding it using in PDO query?

I tried this:

```
$q= "UPDATE table SET post_attending = SUBSTR(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', post_attending, ','), ? , ','), 2, LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(',', post_attending, ','), ? , ',')) - 2) WHERE id = x "
$sql->execute(array(5,5,x));
```

but it leaves me a `,` when there is a 5 or 5 is at the end.

I have read this also `TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(wishes, '(,)? :var (,)?', ''))` don't really figured out the right syntax.

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: @Miguel have you tried my ans

Comment: @Miguel I am sure that my query would also give you the same result and much better than Gordon answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update table
    set post_attending = (case when val like '5,%' then SUBSTRING(val, 3, LENgth(val) - 2)
                               when val like '%,5' then SUBSTRING(val, 1, length(val) - 2)
                               when val = '5' then ''
                               else REPLACE(val, ',5,', ',')
                           end)
```

Answer (score 0):

without using any `CASE` statement, and I believe it would be faster

```
UPDATE table SET post_attending = SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(val, ',5,', ','), ',5', ''), '5,', ''),'5', '')
```